# Playwright selector for combining predicates

Tags: css-selectors, playwright

I need to find the `button` within the `li` that contains in its children both the text `6:00pm` and the text `Alpha`.

```html
<li>
  <div>6:00pm</div>
  <div>Alpha</div>
  <button>Do it!</button>
</li>
<li>
  <div>6:00pm</div>
  <div>Beta</div>
  <button>Do it!</button>
</li>
...
```

I have

```js
li:has(div:text("6:00pm")) button
```

which gives me both `button`s for "6:00pm", but how to limit the selector to also match `Alpha` so I only get one button?

I basically need to add a conjunction to the predicate.

Comment: Try:
page.locator('li:has(div:has-text("6:00pm")), li:has(button:has-text("Alpha"))')
or
page.locator('li:has(div:text("6:00pm")), li:has(button:text("Alpha"))')

Comment: @wojnarto I don't think that works. It retrieves both `<li>`s using an "or" semantic. OP wants "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine `filter` calls to create a logical "and" of your conditions:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.30.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<li>
  <div>6:00pm</div>
  <div>Alpha</div>
  <button>Do it!</button>
</li>
<li>
  <div>6:00pm</div>
  <div>Beta</div>
  <button>Do it!</button>
</li>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const btn = page
    .getByRole("listitem")
    .filter({hasText: "Alpha"})
    .filter({hasText: "6:00pm"})
    .getByRole("button");
  console.log(await btn.textContent()); // => Do it!
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Although this doesn't use the preferred role locator and presupposes a text ordering, the following is also possible:

```js
page.locator("li:text('6:00pm Alpha') button");
```

Comment: Spot on and great reproducible example! Just a minor comment/question, I was curious why you were using `first()` here, as the goal is that this should uniquely find only one anyway, no?

Comment: It makes my intent more explicit, but the filter isn't necessarily unique, unless the nature of the data on your specific site happens to make it so. It's perfectly possible that the HTML had `Alpha` rather than `Beta`, in which case we'd have two matches.

Comment: I can see that. Unless your intent is that it should be the only button that can be found with that final locator? That’s part of the benefit of [locator strictness in Playwright](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#strictness). Using it should rather be the exception if necessary, since the goal is unique locating, as noted in that section: “These methods are not recommended because when your page changes, Playwright may click on an element you did not intend. Instead, follow best practices above to create a locator that uniquely identifies the target element.”

Comment: I see what you mean. My intent was that `count()` and `first()` help prove that it's working, but you're right--there's no need for them because it'd throw otherwise. I'll edit to remove confusion.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha, that makes sense. Sounds good, I see the edit and think the result is great. FWIW, I did already upvote previously though because the answer was exactly what I would’ve recommended, detailed and with a great example, but appreciate the minor tweak to help reduce confusion!